# Coffeescript HTML5 audio pause all other audio elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, coffeescript

I have an many  elements on a page and when a user clicks the "play" or "pause" button i want to pause any other audio that's on the page.

The following code works for the first two clicks every time and then erratically there after and I can't figure out why:

```
$('audio').on 'click', ()->
    $('audio').not($(this))[0].pause()
```

SOLUTION:

```
$('audio').on 'click', ()->
    $playlist = $('audio').not(this)
    for $track in $playlist
        $track.pause()
```

Comment: Can you put it in a fiddle with a one or two other audio elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.not()` can [accept a DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/#not-elements) as well, so you don't strictly need to wrap it in `$()`
- Your current code seems to only be pausing the first `audio` that it finds. You can use something like [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through all results of the selector.

So without seeing more code, this is all I can recommend:

```
$('audio').on 'click', () ->
    $('audio').not(this).each () ->
        this.pause()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. You totally put me on the right track. I'll update with my question with the solution.